# Associating a UITableView with a TableViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, uitableview

Can anyone describe how it is possible to have a TableViewController with its xib file having a at its root and the uitableview as a subview?
I believe the TVController somehow assumes that UITableView will fill the entire area.
Why is that?
I have a really specific need to build a kind of side and bottom tabbed interface with a UITableView as its main area. Pressing tabs changes the predicate for the fetchedresultscontroller etc etc.
The reason I want this is because of the breadth and depth of the data categories in the data model. I rally need to flatten the menu structure a lot...other wise with a table and navbar controller structure, user experience will be akin to sinking to ever deeper depths of a cavern!
My idea is tried and true in other paradigms...in iOS it almost looks like it's Apple's way or the highway. I am OK with APPLE of course no gripe.
But I really would like to create this.
I tried adding a new tableviewcontroller complete with xib and then removing the UITableView in IB and replacing with a UIView and a UITableView as a subview, hooking up (I believe) the delegate to the file's owner.
I created an IV tableView for when I want to reference it and again used IB to hook it up in IB

Try to run it and it whines that...
 [UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "TabbedTableController" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
Really can't seem to get my head around what the issue is here.
There doesn't appear to be anymore I can do to hook the UITableView up!

Any help would be terrific. I'll send you a Christmas card in desperation :^)
Also...why should it be so and how strict is this UITableView fullscreen thing?
Enlighten me if you can. The docs I have read don't want to.

Regards
Keith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A UITableViewController does assume that the root view (i.e. the controller's `view` property) will be a UITableView, thus the table view fills the screen. When you need a view that combines UITableView with other top level views, you will need to do a little more work but it's not hard:

Your view controller will not subclass UITableView. Instead, do this:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController 
  <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView* tableView;
```

In Interface Builder, drop in a `UITableView` and whatever other controls you need. The table view can be any size and in any location in the view hierarchy. Also in Interface Builder, ctrl-drag from the table view to your VC and set the `delegate` and `dataSource` outlets, and ctrl-drag from your VC to the table view to set the `tableView` outlet.

Your view controller implementation should be the typical table view controller implementation: `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, etc.

A `UITableViewController` is more or less just all of the above work packaged up into a single unit for you.

Comment: ah of course thanks.
still don't understand why that restriction

Comment: EDIT: Yes I now understand on reflection why this restriction is so.
Subclassing. A UITableViewController is a ViewController subclass but conforming to the required delegate and datasource. So why would anyone want to change something built for a specific reason like that. Go make your own. Can you tell with my slow realisations on how things work I MUST be a reformed .NET coder?
Thankyou again esker